# Doubt about the Prophethood of Mohammad because of his marriages

Tags: practical-islam, sunni, muslim-practices

I have doubts about Mohammad being a messenger from Allah. 
I am troubled by him having 13 wives and 
his marriage to Aisha at the young age of 9.
Can someone explain these to me and help resolve my doubts?

Comment: Take a look at http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17534/11-wives-of-prophet-muhammad-saw and http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/5851/12537

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why prophet PBUH has married more than four wife?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13297/why-prophet-pbuh-has-married-more-than-four-wife)

Comment: See also: "[Why are Muslims allowed to marry up to four women?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/76/9123)"

Comment: @azam it's not all replica it still has it's own originality

Answer (score 4):

All Praise to Allah The Most Magnificent and blessings of him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

Thanks for your interest sister and asking a question which shows you are searching for the Truth.

From the above mentioned links in comments you would be aware now that the age matter has been debatable for long and not concluding into one exact age. Apart from this it is also important to state that

**According to the Bible**:

Abraham had **three** wives ([Genesis 16:1](http://biblehub.com/genesis/16-1.htm), [16:3](http://biblehub.com/genesis/16-3.htm), [25:1](http://biblehub.com/genesis/25-1.htm))

Moses had **two** wives (Exodus 2:21, 18:1-6; Numbers 12:1)

Jacob had **four** wives (Genesis 29:23, 29:28, 30:4, 30:9)

David had at least **18** wives ([1 Samuel 18:27](http://biblehub.com/1_samuel/18-27.htm), [25:39-44](http://biblehub.com/context/1_samuel/25-39.htm); [2 Samuel 3:3](http://biblehub.com/2_samuel/3-3.htm), [3:4-5](http://biblehub.com/context/2_samuel/3-4.htm), [5:13](http://biblehub.com/2_samuel/5-13.htm), [12:7-8](http://biblehub.com/context/2_samuel/12-7.htm), [12:24](http://biblehub.com/2_samuel/12-24.htm), [16:21-23](http://biblehub.com/context/2_samuel/16-21.htm))

Solomon had **700** wives ([1 Kings 11:3](http://biblehub.com/1_kings/11-3.htm)).
(Please note that the words in the references could be or could not be correct as that were adulterated afterwards as we see Allah Swt clarifies in Quran regarding Torah and Prophet Solomon too).

Now who knows exactly what would be their age.
It does not effect a belief of a Muslim ,because a Muslim believe on Allah as one,, His Angels His Holy Books and All His Prophets,, The Last Day.

All His Messengers including Prophet Adam ,Moses ,David,Solomon,Jesus,Muhammad (peace be upon all of them) brought the same message to worship only one God, Now They married more than one so one of the reason was to spread more message and knowledge like Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him married in different tribes which helps in spreading Islamic knowledge among them,wives of the Prophet spread the knowledge to so many group of people and Ayesha may Allah be pleased with her played an important role in conveying messages and teachings of Prophet to Companions.Most of the prophet wives were widows and he married them for protection, his life gave us a message of love,peace and caring.Apart from all the propagandas made in  modern world against his marriages Michael Hart a nonmuslim has chosen Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him as number 1 in his book [100 most influential people](http://www.biographyonline.net/people/100-most-influential.html) in the world and said "My choice of Muhammad to lead the world's most influential persons may surprise some readers and may be questioned by others, but he was the only man in history who was supremely successful on both the religious and secular levels."

Now if some one says and believes Allah as One and Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him as his Messenger ( La ilaha illAllah Muhammad ur Rasulullah in Arabic) then He is a Muslim which means he submits himself to the will of Allah and by reading the Quran which is the Final Holy book of God one could learn the whole way to live with love and peace.if you have some more queries visit www.islamreligion.com

Allah and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: I reckon pointing out to some information from Bible made your nice answer more admirable. Jazak-Allah-Khaira

Comment: I don't see how child molestation in the Bible makes child molestation attributed to Muhammad less reprehensible.

Comment: hello thanks for your comment ,could you define me what is the coherence with child molestation in the bible or else.

Comment: @G.Bach  You need to see this too https://discover-the-truth.com/2013/09/09/age-of-consent-in-european-american-history/

Comment: Child rape under the cover of marriage having been legal 100 years ago in Europe or America or anywhere else does not make it any more moral.

Comment: Now if you have problem with the Global accredited consent or Law then no one could help you out in it except for Allah Swt.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know where you are from, but one thing that i know is that marriage in in early ages is still tradition in part's of ME.
i have my uncle who was 28 year's old and his wife was 12 when they married...

aside tradition, Arab girl's had big physics...
there are some saying's that this one wife of prophet was like 12 year's old when married to prophet(Shia believe)... but that doesn't change anything...

as of multiple wives, well, Arab's still have multiple wives like i know so many Arab's with 3-4 wives...
and also there is a saying(Shia believe) that because those women had lost their husband's in battle and had no one to protect them,the prophet married to them but never had sex with them. they were saved and protected just because had the prophet's name on them...(i have heard it from low educated shia cleric's and i don't know if grand ayatollah's of shia would say the same thing or not!)

Comment: Remarking of the following point looks related and interesting as you remarked "aside tradition, Arab girl's had big physics...". Jazak Allah Khaira.

Answer (score 0):

Most of his wives he married were married for a reason. Some of them, lost their husband and were poor. The Prophet pbuh married them to save their son's lives. And for the 9 year, he was ENGAGED but not married with Ayesha (R) for 2 years.
There are also more logical reasons behind marrying 13 wives and a 12 year old girl.
There are pages all over the internet, you can learn from there or ask any good scholar to be clear in this matter.

[enter link description here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad's_wives)

Answer (score -1):

This may seem abusive at the first...but you must question that could there be alternative reasons for his marriages as well? Or he did it solely for his pleasure? Could some of them have happened because of political reasons? Did he have them all at the same time? How did he treat them? If you concluded that he did it for his own pleasure then put Muhammad away right away! As no prophet is summoned for pleasure!

Don't think that it was necessarily a pleasant thing for the prophet to have multiple wives, ( If they were temporary wives just for his pleasure it would have been a pleasant thing, but if they are permanent wives that you would have to deal with, then it would definitely mean that you are not after pleasure) ...so many times men are tested by their wives and how they react...so many times

Back those ages...women were different and that girls were becoming mothers very earlier than now...

As some answers mentioned prophets are unique beings...they are very much like us but with unique abilities, features, traits, responsibilities...

Also some scholars refute that the prophet had 9 or 14 wives all at once...rather it happened through a period of time.